# wget post form data when form is using javascript onClick method

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post, wget

I want to post data to a html form using wget --post-data, but the form partially uses a javascript `onClick` handler to submit the data.

Here is the form tag:

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="/Postbox/index.xhtml?conversationContext=1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

This form contains several images in div containers that have javascript onClick methods to submit the form like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('dab','j_id945854552_5af96283');" title="Delete PDF" class="ang_delete">Delete PDF</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="return jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('j_id945854552_5af9636d:hero'), event,'return myfaces.oam.submitForm(\'test\',\'j_id945854552_5af9636d:hero\');');" id="j_id945854552_5af9636d:hero" tabindex="">Find PDF</a>
```

Now I wonder how I can submit this form. There are no name or value tags withing the containers for these buttons, so I am quite clueless here. I tried to post data to the "test" form like this:

> `--post-data "j_id945854552_5af9636d:hero"`

but this is obviously senseless.

Does any of the experts here have an idea?

I cannot find the javascript method `myfaces.oam.submitForm` in the source somehwere, but googleing shows that it seems to be common method.